# When updating user information viewmodel is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, null, viewmodel, nullreferenceexception

**Error:** NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Web.Controllers.ManageController.ChangeUser(BaseViewModel model) in ManageController.cs
+
user.FirstName = model.ChangeUserViewModel.FirstName;

I cannot understand why I am getting this error, could you please help me find what I am doing wrong ?

What i am trying to achieve is updating the user information trough my viewmodel.

Can you please advise if the way i am trying to do it is correct?

**BaseViewModel:**

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public IndexViewModel IndexViewModel { get; set; }
    public ChangeUserViewModel ChangeUserViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

**ChangeUserViewModel:**

```
public class ChangeUserViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "Profile Picture")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [MaxFileSize(5* 1024 * 1024)]
    [AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".tif" })]

    public IFormFile ProfilePicture { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        var model = new BaseViewModel
        {
            IndexViewModel = new IndexViewModel
            {
                HasPassword = await _userManager.HasPasswordAsync(user),
                PhoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user),
                TwoFactor = await _userManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user),
                Logins = await _userManager.GetLoginsAsync(user),
                BrowserRemembered = await _signInManager.IsTwoFactorClientRememberedAsync(user),
                AuthenticatorKey = await _userManager.GetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user),
            },
            ChangeUserViewModel = new ChangeUserViewModel
            {
                FirstName = user.FirstName,
                LastName = user.LastName,
                Email = user.Email
            }
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeUser(BaseViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
        }
        
        var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        if (user != null)
        {
            user.FirstName = model.ChangeUserViewModel.FirstName;
            user.LastName = model.ChangeUserViewModel.LastName;
            user.Email = model.ChangeUserViewModel.Email;

            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        }

        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model BaseViewModel
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Manage your account";
}

    <h2 class="content-heading pt-0">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user-circle text-muted mr-1"></i> User Profile
    </h2>
    
    <form asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="ChangeUser" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row push">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p class="text-muted">
                    Your account’s vital info.
                </p>
            </div>
            
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dm-profile-edit-firstname">Firstname</label>
                    <input asp-for="ChangeViewModel.FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" id="dm-profile-edit-firstname" name="dm-profile-edit-firstname" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dm-profile-edit-lastname">Lastname</label>
                    <input asp-for="ChangeViewModel.LastName" type="text" class="form-control" id="dm-profile-edit-lastname" name="dm-profile-edit-lastname">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dm-profile-edit-email">Email Address</label>
                    <input asp-for="ChangeViewModel.Email" type="email" class="form-control" id="dm-profile-edit-email" name="dm-profile-edit-email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Your Avatar</label>
                    <div class="push">
                        <img class="img-avatar" src="@Url.Action("ProfilePicture", "Account" )" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input asp-for="ChangeViewModel.ProfilePicture" type="file" class="custom-file-input js-custom-file-input-enabled" data-toggle="custom-file-input" id="ProfilePicture" name="ProfilePicture">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="ProfilePicture">Choose a new avatar</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-alt-primary">
                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle mr-1"></i> Update Profile
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I can see in your code BaseViewModel and BaseManageViewModel, ChangeUserViewModel and ChangeVitalUserInfoViewModel. What is your real code? Nobody can help till you post your real code. The code you posted will not be compiled.

Comment: Hi @Sergey thnx for mentioning it. I updated the code

Comment: Hi Sergey, I don't understand your answer. 

I have one ManageController, in the controller I have multiple ActionResults (ChangeUser, ChangePassword, AddPhoneNumber). For all of those ActionResults I have a ViewModel. ChangeUserViewModel, ChangePasswordViewModel.... 

Now I need to have one View. In that view I use the BaseViewModel. I need in that view multiple forms for every single ActionResult. 

The problem is that when I hit submit in the ChangeUser form I get a null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the controller didn't recieve the `BaseViewModel` when do post request from view. I suggest you could use `Newtonsoft’s Json.NET` instead of `System.Text.Json`.

Step1. Install the following Nuget package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

Step2.
If you are migrating from an existing project you’ll have a call to “AddMvc()” which you can then tack onto it like so :

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

However in new `.NET Core` 3+ projects, you have a different set of calls replace MVC. So you’ll probably have one of the following :

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Then, place your breakpoint in your controller code to check the value of `BaseViewModel model`.